# having trouble accessing my json file from my assets folder

Tags: android, json, assets, filenotfoundexception, android-assets

In my android app I can't access my json file in my assets folder. It keeps giving me a FileNotFoundException.

Without reading it directly into a InputStream I want to get the location of the json file instead. I have tried using /main/assets/data.json or ///android_assets/data.json or /assets/data.json.

The main purpose of this is to pass a string that holds the location of the json file to another class.

Is there a way to have the location of the json file in the assets file be returned to me? Is there anywhere I can check to make sure my app recognizes that the assets folder is even a part of the application?

EDIT:

In my Activity

```
public void loadData(){
    String location = "file:///android_assets/data.json";
    JSONHandler json = new JSONHandler();
    List<ListItemObject> list = json.getJSONFile(location);
}
```

In my JSONHandler Class

```
public ListItemObject getJSONFile(String Location){
File file = new File(address);
    InputStream in;
    InputStreamReader isr;
    JsonReader jr;
    List<SMRListItemObject> messages = null;
    try{
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8");
        jr = new JsonReader(isr);
        messages = readMessagesArray(jr);
        jr.close();
        isr.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Exception", "File Not Found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Exception", "IO problem");
    }
    return messages;
}
```

The line where I am calling the getJSONFile is where I am getting the FileNotFoundException being thrown.

Error message:

```
02-26 02:38:01.086  27165-27165/com.example.generalcounsel.sm       D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-26 02:38:01.817  27165-27165/com.example.generalcounsel.sm D/Exception﹕ File Not Found
02-26 02:38:01.817  27165-27165/com.example.generalcounsel.sm D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-26 02:13:59.690  25369-25369/com.example.generalcounsel.sm W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a5da0)
02-26 02:13:59.690  25369-25369/com.example.generalcounsel.sm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.generalcounsel.sm, PID: 25369
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.generalcounsel.sm/com.example.generalcounsel.sm.ListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.generalcounsel.sm.ListActivity.loadData(ListActivity.java:72)
        at com.example.generalcounsel.sm.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
        at    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
```

Comment: please put your code to show to where are you making mistake

Comment: @Vaishali I don't have much code right now. I have a string which is supposed to hold the full path of the json file in my assets folder (this is whats not working). All paths I try like the ones listed above haven't worked. Anyway then the string will be passed to my json parser class for further manipulation.

Comment: there might be issue other than the path, plz post your code so that the community might be able to help you

Comment: @Neji edited my post with my code and error message

Comment: exception is in loadData() post code of the function!

Comment: @Neji my apologies those three lines above in my activity are in a method called loadData. I edited my code to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try opening file using following way

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream ims = assetManager.open("data.json");
```

Also, **getAssets()** only works with a context, you may need context to call it in class other than activity.

Read json file from assets using following code

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("file_name.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

and then parse into a json object using following code

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json_return_by_the_function);
```

Comment: Is there anyway though to get the full path of the json file in terms of a string?

Comment: there is no absolute path as assets are stored in apk.
Still, you can use file:///android_asset to reference to files in assets